# Set Azure Websites AlwaysOn with Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

For Visual Studio Team Services continuous integration, I would like to disable "Always On", release, then enable it. (because NewRelic need to disable AlwaysOn when publishing, it use specific dll)

Can we set AlwaysOn with Azure CLI ? I didn't find it in the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
azure webapp config set RGName WebAppName --alwayson true
```

source: azure webapp config --help

> Update 8/28/2018:
>
> The syntax has changed. Now it's
>
> ```
> az webapp config set --name mywebapp --resource-group myresourcegroup --always-on true
> ```
>
> See
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-config-set

Comment: Ok my bad, I misunderstood different CLI modes (ASM/ARM). Thanks !

Comment: so does this work for you? if it does, kindly mark it as answer ;)

Comment: I'm testing it right now, don't worry I will if it works !

Comment: The syntax has changed.  Now it's `az webapp config set --name mywebapp --resource-group myresourcegroup --always-on true`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-config-set